# tensorflow - CTC loss decreasing but decoder ouput empty

Tags: tensorflow

I am using tensorflow's `ctc_cost` and `ctc_greedy_decoder`. When I train the model minimizing `ctc_cost`, the cost whent down, but when I decode it always out put nothing. Is there any reason this might happen? My code is as following.

I am wondering if I preprocessed the data correctly. I am predicting sequnces of phones on given frames of fbank features. There are 48 phones (48 classes), and each frame has 69 features. I set `num_classes` to 49 so logits will have dimension `(max_time_steps, num_samples, 49)`. And for my sparse tensor, I have my values range from 0 to 47 (48 reserved for blank). I never added blanks to my data, I don't think I should? (Should I do anything like that??)

When trained, the cost decreases after each iteration and epochs, but edit distance never decreased. In fact it stays at 1 because the decoder almost always predict and empty sequence. Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

```py
graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():

    inputs  = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, None, num_features])
    targets = tf.sparse_placeholder(tf.int32)
    seq_len = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])
    seq_len_t = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])
    cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(num_hidden)
    stack = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([cell] * num_layers)
    outputs, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(stack, inputs, seq_len, dtype=tf.float32)
    outputs, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(stack, inputs, seq_len, dtype=tf.float32)

    input_shape = tf.shape(inputs)
    outputs = tf.reshape(outputs, [-1, num_hidden])
    W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([num_hidden,
                                     num_classes],
                                    stddev=0.1))

    b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0., shape=[num_classes]))


    logits = tf.matmul(outputs, W) + b

    logits = tf.reshape(logits, [input_shape[0], -1, num_classes])

    logits = tf.transpose(logits, (1, 0, 2))

    loss = tf.nn.ctc_loss(targets, logits, seq_len)
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(loss)

    decoded, log_probabilities = tf.nn.ctc_greedy_decoder(logits, seq_len, merge_repeated=True)
    optimizer = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(initial_learning_rate, 0.1).minimize(cost)
    err = tf.reduce_mean(tf.edit_distance(tf.cast(decoded[0],tf.int32), targets))
    saver = tf.train.Saver()    

with tf.Session(graph=graph) as session:

    X, Y, ids, seq_length, label_to_int, int_to_label = get_data('train')

    session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    print(seq_length)

    num_batches = len(X)//batch_size + 1



    for epoch in range(epochs):
        print ('epoch'+str(epoch))
        for batch in range(num_batches):
            input_X, target_input, seq_length_X = get_next_batch(batch,X, Y ,seq_length,batch_size)
            feed = {inputs: input_X ,
            targets: target_input,
            seq_len: seq_length_X}

            print ('epoch'+str(epoch))
            _, print_cost, print_er = session.run([optimizer, cost, err], feed_dict = feed)
            print('epoch '+ str(epoch)+' batch '+str(batch)+ ' cost: '+str(print_cost)+' er: '+str(print_er))

    save_path = saver.save(session, '/tmp/model.ckpt')
    print('model saved')

    X_t, ids_t, seq_length_t = get_data('test')

    feed_t = {inputs: X_t, seq_len: seq_length_t}   
    print(X.shape)
    print(X_t.shape)
    print(type(seq_length_t[0]))


    de, lo = session.run([decoded[0], log_probabilities],feed_dict = feed_t)
    with open('predict.pickle', 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump((de, lo), f)
```

Comment: is the network fully trained (training error stagnating)? Because empty labellings are usually encountered at the beginning of the training. E.g. search for "The intriguing blank label in CTC". And no, you don't have to add blanks to your target labellings. Those blanks are just for (CTC) internal usage.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem and solved by increasing the initial learning rate.

In addition, outputting the LER on the validation set is necessary to check the progress of the training process.